# Understanding "in" keyword in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In my attempt to really understand Javascript, rather than being a copy and paste Javascript googler, I'm going through Eloquent Javascript E-book and I happen to cross the following example:

```
var chineseBox = {};
chineseBox.content = chineseBox;
show("content" in chineseBox);
show("content" in chineseBox.content);
```

Surprisingly, they both output `true`. The book itself claims, "The operator `in` can be used to test whether an object has a certain property. It produces a boolean."

I understand that `show("content" in chineseBox);` is looking for a `content` property which it does have, its value being `chineseBox`. However, why does the second `show()` work?

To test further, I tried:

```
show("content" in chineseBox.content.content); //true

show("contents" in chineseBox.contents.content); //type error: undefined

show("contents" in chineseBox.content.contents); // invalid "in" operand
```

Question is basically, variable chineseBox{} doesn't have content property... or does it?

Comment: `chineseBox` has a `content` property, and it is a reference to `chineseBox` itself. So any depth of `.content` will produce `true`.

Comment: You are getting the errors in your second two examples because the are using contents instead of content

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key is this line:

```
chineseBox.content = chineseBox;
```

This gives `chineseBox` a reference to itself. So:

```
show(chineseBox.content === chineseBox);
```

You should see *this* will also output `true`.

Therefore `'content'` is in `chineseBox` as well as `chineseBox.content` (and `chineseBox.content.content` and so on) because they're all the same object, which *does* have a `content` property.

---

Let's look at your second and third examples. Why does one give a `TypeError` while the other complains about an invalid `in` operand?

In the second example, you have:

```
show("contents" in chineseBox.contents.content);
```

In order for the `in` operator to test whether the specified property ("content**s**") is in the specified object, it first has to evaluate what that object *is*. You get a type error because `chineseBox.contents` is `undefined`, and so you can't access its `content` property because there's no object to access.

Contrast this with the third example:

```
show("contents" in chineseBox.content.contents);
```

Now *here*, the `in` operator at least gets farther than it did in the second example. The `chineseBox.content` property *does* exist, and accessing *its* content**s** property gives you `undefined`. So there is no error there. But then you get an error with the `in` keyword itself because you can't check if a property is in `undefined`.

In other words, in the second example it's like you're asking "Are there any elves in Santa's house?" Santa doesn't exist, so there is no such place as "Santa's house." In the third example it's more like you're asking "Where is the oval office in Obama's brown house?" Obama exists, but he doesn't have a brown house.

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks for the also addressing the "contents" examples. I simply put it there due to my lack of understanding that chineseBox had a reference to itself.

Answer (score 3):

```
chineseBox.content = chineseBox;
```

Because of the self-reference, notice that `chineseBox` is the same object as `chineseBox.content`. Meaning `chineseBox`, `chineseBox.content`, `chineseBox.content.content`, `chineseBox.content.content.content`, ad infinitum, all refer to the same object.

```
show("content" in chineseBox);
show("content" in chineseBox.content);
show("content" in chineseBox.content.content);
show("content" in chineseBox.content.content.content);
show("content" in chineseBox.content.content.content.content);
show("content" in chineseBox.content.content.content.content.content);
```

(In your tests, beware the difference between `content` and `contents` with an 's'.)